# How to add/wait for user input?

Tags: python

How do you limit the input to 6 characters as well as catch if any special characters were inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `raw_input()` ? (http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

**EDITED TO ADD:**

Try something like this:

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    ssid_end = sys.argv[1].lower()
else:
    ssid_end = raw_input("==> ").lower()
```

Comment: So you're saying you're running `python wifi.py [something]` and it raises this IndexError ?

Comment: I added "userinput = raw_input('--> ')" at the top below both "import" and once I run the program and insert the 6 characters it shows me this error. Otherwise it's fine and I can run the script without raw_input()

Comment: Ah of course if you run the script without any parameters you shouldn't try reading `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: WOW ! Hats off dude, love you so much ! It works with your code, thank you, thank you so much !